# Are there any time irreversible processes on earth which aren't due to the sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, thermal-radiation, reversibility

The sun is very hot. The earth is cold. Energy always flows from hot to cold systems. Due to the temperature difference, useful energy can be imparted onto earth (i.e., blackbody radiation from the sun which has a higher temperature than earth's temperature). Is there any time irreversible process on earth which is NOT due to sunlight?

Life is caused by photosynthesis, which is due to this sunlight. Weather, wind, the evaporation of water, this is all caused by sunlight heating up the ground. I can't think of any time irreversible processes on earth not due to sunlight. (Using a telescope and looking at other astrophysical objects doesn't count.) If the earth was just floating in space, would there be no way to tell the difference between forwards in time and backwards in time?

Comment: Geothermal energy sources have also been implicated in the origin of life. You might be interested in these [two](https://youtu.be/vwXDGkxwU7M) [talks](https://youtu.be/10cVVHKCRWw)

Comment: a volcano, an earthquake, a tsunami, continental drift, ...

Comment: Burn wood, or any material... mix sugar, salt with water, break anything... all of these are irreversible processes that doesn't require the Sun to exist.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik For the wood/sugar/salt example, I would have to instigate those actions, and the only reason I (or the biological products of wood and sugar) is due to the sun. On pluto, no one is mixing salt with water, which was exactly my question. But to the other commenters, yes, geothermal sources are indeed a counterexample.

Comment: There were naturally occurring fission-based nuclear reactors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geothermal processes including lava cooling and radioactive decay in the earth. That is certainly irreversible and is due to the material and the gravitational collapse of the earth itself, not the sun.

Comment: That, or mixing sugar with water.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Any action taken by humans—or indeed any species who depended (or whose ancestry depended) in any way on the Sun—can be handwaved away according to the original question.

Comment: You could also include processes like dissolving minerals in water which don't require life, humans, or photosynthesis.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I do not see the question in this way. For example, if the Sun were to disappear right now, humans wouldn't probably survive for many more years/decades, but we sure would not go extinct instantly.